# Hide, disable user interface buttons or touch when camera intent open | android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

Is there any way to prevent a kid from clicking the buttons in the camera app when the intent open ?

Here's the code i use

```
public void openFrontCamera() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
        }


        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);


        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent student = getIntent();
        student.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();

        startActivity(student);

        Intent student1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(student1);
    }
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Usually, the point behind `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is to allow the user to take a picture, and in many camera apps, that will involve clicking a button. If you do not want the user clicking buttons, what is the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` for?

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, how can i fix that ?

Comment: I guess I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @CommonsWare i want to open a screen showing the front camera, without any user interface, just a clean screen

Comment: Integrate a camera library (Google's CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.), so you can control the user interface.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you post a an example of code ? or link ?